# Passing the result of a function to a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list in controllerA - controllerA also has a function that determines if an item in that list has been imported.  I'd like to pass this boolean into each of the listed objects' directives (so controllerB - the controller for each of the objects - can see if its object has been imported), but it's not working as I'd hoped.

I have the following (simplified) in my HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr objectpane object="object" objectIsImported="objectIsImported(object)"></tr>
</tbody>
```

objectIsImported is supposed to be passing a boolean down to the objectPane instance.

This view is paired to an ng-controller (controllerA) that has the following function defined:

```
$scope.objectIsImported = function(object) {
    alert("never gets hit");
};
```

objectpane directive has this:

```
aoo.directive('objectpane', ['$log', function ($log) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: '/App/objectmanager/objectpane.html',
    scope: {
        object: "=",
        objectIsImported: "="
    },
    controller: 'ObjectPaneController'
};
}]);
```

Within ObjectPaneController (ControllerB) I have this:

```
$scope.alreadyImported = $scope.objectIsImported;  // from scope in directive
```

The problem is that the $scope.objectIsImported from controllerA is not getting hit, ever.  What am I doing wrong?  Everything else is working between the controllers / directive, it's just that passing this function result down to the directive doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Does it work if you change the html attribute to `object-is-imported` (hyphens instead of capital letters)?

Comment: @Martin wow, yes it does.  Angular lesson: learned.  Feel free to make this the answer and I'll mark it accepted :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `objectIsImported` should be changed to lowercase with hyphens: `object-is-imported`.